# Trying to force functional component to un-mount, in React / Ionic-React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, ionic4

I have a project built with ionic-react CLI. There's feature of ionic-react, and it's implementation of react-router, is that page-components stay mounted and get hidden when you change routes. Which is proving problematic for me sometimes.

So, how can I manually force a component to unmount? There may be a react way to do it, and maybe an ionic-react way I don't know about. Anyone know how I could handle this.

Comment: Are you sure that components remains mounted on route change, even when they should not be rendered in active route? I am not familiar with ionic but react-router should handle mounting/unmounting for you. Exception is when you have nested routes - where parent route (and component parent route renders) is always mounted

Comment: Are you sure you have `react-router`, or are you using some ionic version of a routing library?

Comment: Ionic in react uses some additional code on top of react-router, but uses a plain react-router dependency for most of its routing logic. That's something I'm sure of, and not really what I'm asking. And yes, I'm sure that routed views stay in mounted with what is essentially a display: none on them when not in view.

Comment: any luck on this? I am so sick of this issue haha about to throw away ionic router lol

Comment: @PaulSanchez Switched to react native and never looked back